Why does this push-pull converter fail?
Consider the following circuit of a push-pull converter. I would be interested to learn why you think it fails (MOSFET and controller).

The controller is a UCC28084. The MOSFETs are SSM3K361R (i.e. not the 2310B claimed in the schematic). The transformer is a 750315240.
The converter runs completely fine, until it is suddenly dead. So far, it has never failed during operation, but was only found dead when the device was turned on. That is, it either fails during turn-off/on or even while idling on the shelf.
When the damage has occured, one of the MOSFETs is found with a short between all three terminals, but with no discernible damage to its package. The second MOSFET is fine. The controller is also found with a short between VIN and GND. The controller shows a small amount of externally visible damage:

The converter experiences the greatest load during turn-on when charging the secondary side capacitance (100 µF), during 1-2 ms. Current is limited due to peak-current-mode control, to about 1 A peak current.
Unfortunately, I wasn't able to get a scope shot of the switching waveforms during this period. According to simulations, the drain voltage of the MOSFETs stays in the 80-90 V area when at peak current of 1 A. In case, the leakage inductance of the transformer is larger than expected, this could be higher, but the MOSFETs have an avalanche rating of 3.5 A. Below are scope shots of the normal operation, when current consumption is much lower than 1 A.
Secondary-side switch node "Sec1":

Primary-side switch node "Pri1":

MOSFET gate voltage:


What voltage margin do you have on the MOSFET (DS and GS) in the worst case, during power on, steady state or turn off? Also, did you check all of the IC pin voltages? They shall not swing below ground (or exceed their max rating) and neg. bias is one of the major failure causes. The measurement must  be done with a probe without pigtail, the spring must go to the IC GND pin and you probe each pin like that. If you see neg. spikes, with a significant duration beyond 100-200 ns, you may have a problem there. If the IC latches up, it can easily fail. Unless the FET dies first and fries the IC.

What is the state of the other components? Especially the Snubber Diodes D1 and D2? My fist guess would be the Snubber failing.

@kruemi Diodes are fine. Each time when a failure occurs, after replacing only the MOSFETs and controller, the converter operates perfectly again.

@VerbalKint As I wrote, I couldnt manage to capture actual scope data during the max current phase (turn-on, charging secondary el-cap). During this phase the margin to max voltage is small (its a 100 V MOSFET) peaking to ~90V in sims, but the MOSFET are avalanche rated. During normal operation, the max voltage has more than 70V of margin before exceeding VDS. Which pin of the controller could hypothetically be exposed to negative transients? Based on the circuit I couldn't imagine that for any of the pins.

I would not trust sims to check the max voltage on the switches. There are many stray contributors that are affecting the waveforms and may engender highly-peaking oscillatory waveforms. Also, keep in mind that diodes, as fast as they can be at turn-on, have a forward transit time which generates some overshoot before hard-clamping. If too low a margin, bye-bye the MOSFET. Also, never use a MOSFET as a transient voltage suppressor: the avalanche must only be accidental (e.g. during surge tests) but not permanent.

Negative bias of switching controllers is a plague for power designers and QA departments. If you look at the IC specs, it is specified -0.3 V as the very max neg. pin voltage you can apply. Beyond this value, you will forward-bias the ESD Zener diode and start injecting electrons in the substrate with all goofy consequences: malfunction like Q and Qb high at the same time (boostrapped drivers in 1/2-bridge) or latch up as you fire a hidden SCR in the layout. This often kills the IC. This neg. comes from parasitic ringing which reaches pins like DRV or CS for instance. Check the pins! ^_^

@VerbalKint I don't have a super tight probe, but all the suspicious pins on the controller (Drivers and CS) look severly overdamped and never negative. However, the thing you said about the avalanches: If the MOSFET doesn't survive repeated avalanches during a period of about 1 ms, would that cause a fault similar to described above? I.e. one MOSFET totally cross-shorted, and then the controller perhaps dying as a secondary effect as one of its drivers would be essentially shorted to ground via the broken MOSFET... ?

@tobalt that it's working does not always imply that the diodes are ok. They are there to dampen the voltage spikes when the transistors switch off. If those diodes are broken, that circuit can work for a wile and fail or fail immediately...

I suggest changing the resistors R2 and R8 from 100 Ohm to 0 Ohm. With 100 Ohm series resistors the snubber diodes are ineffective. If the MOSFET turns off at 1 A current, 100 Ohms in series with the diodes will increase the D-S voltage by just 100 V. I don't see the transformer's leakage inductance specified, but it may be necessary to reduce the resistance of R13 (22k) to fit within the 100 V maximum voltage of the MOSFET. A reduced value of R13 will require a resistor with a higher power rating.

One more change that seems essential. Replace the 40 V D1 and D2 diodes with a 100 V model (e.g. SS110 or similar).

@csabahu Thanks something along those lines was the initial draft. However, in the sims there was a lot of resonance through the two diodes' capacitance and transformer's leakage inductance. The 100 ohm resistors were meant to damp this, but I agree something lower like 33 ohm is perhaps safer, even if it risks some EMI.
